# Increasing current delivered to ESC (pwm signal)

Tags: pwm, current-source

I am curious if it is possible to increase the amount of current (delivered to ESC) in a pwm signal without changing the signals period or duty cycle. I have access to 5v sources on each ESC. I'm using the intel Edison which allows me to set the necessary period and duty cycle, only the source current from the pwm lines is too small and is not recognized by the ESC.

I am 3000% sure this is the problem, since I produced the exact same signal from an Arduino and a signal generator, which were readily accepted by the ESC. Both sourced around 50-60 mA while the Edison only sources 5-10 mA on pwm.

I am using the intel mini breakout board and level shifting the 1.8v native Edison output to 5 volts with a 4 channel bidirectional level shifter from spark fun.

I greatly appreciate any advice or suggestions!

Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: If a digital input is demanding that kind of current then there is something wrong there. My suspicion is actually with your understanding of how these things work. Of more interest, instead of the current, is what *voltage* the PWM signal is.

Comment: I know these things, trust me, it is the current. The ESC accepts pwm from anywhere between 50 -500 hz and regardless of the frequency the motor speed is determined by the pulse width in between 1-2 ms. Max speed being close to 2 ms and min being closer to 1.

Comment: -1 If you are going to insist that you know what you are talking about while fixating on something that is obviously not the actual issue, this is not the place to ask for help.

Comment: Your post needs to include a picture of your oscilloscope test of the output while the ESC is connected, a description of the sequence you are going through to unlock/arm the ESC, and a link to the manual of said ESC.

Comment: How are you measuring those "50-60ma" figures?

Comment: @ChrisStratton How do you know that is not the issue? Apologies If I seem persistent about something you disagree with. As for the arming sequence, these ESC's do not require one. I purchased them as part of a kit on eBay and they are likely mislabeled (not what eBay says they are: Emax 12A w/simonk). They beep a low tone followed by a high tone, and then start to spin depending on if the pulse width is above about 1.2 ms. But they always beep low then high when the pwm from arduino is connected.

Comment: @pjc50 I used an digital ammeter to look at current.

Comment: If you are using an ammeter to measure "the current of" a digital signal, you need to re-take circuits 101 and stop arguing that you know what you are doing.  On the other hand, if you want to get to the bottom of this, probe the signal **while the ESC is connected**, snap a picture of the scope with your phone, and post that.

Comment: Exactly - if you just had the ammeter in series while running the 400Hz small duty cycle signal, I wouldn't expect it to give reliable results. Actual drive current will be a pain to measure; try probes on opposite sides of a 100 ohm resistor and see what you get. If the 100R stops it working, then that's useful information too.

Comment: Oh, and is the grounding arrangement OK on all of this setup?

Comment: @pjc50 - to get the reported 50-60ma currents, the ammeter was obviously not in series, but rather *shorting* the output to ground.  Under those conditions, the Arduino would not be getting the level up to 5v, either.

Comment: .. which introduces yet another possibility, that shorting the output to ground to measure it has killed it.

Comment: The symptom of a voltage source being unable to supply the required current would be that it is unable to maintain the desired voltage.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz bingo. I have connected the oscilloscope and esc concurrently. The high voltage on the oscilloscope is 2v which I now believe is the problem as david pointed out. Apologies for me being thick in the head. The 5v source is from the ESC's which are powered by a 11.1v lipo. So does this mean the voltage is dropping because the Edison isn't supplying enough current?

Comment: @ThomasKirven No, the level shifter probably isn't. What are you using to shift the level?

Comment: I am using this https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009 but since the voltage has dropped from 5v to 2v while plugged into the ESC, isn't that the likely problem?

Comment: Much like tuskiomi's original circuit, that sparkfun thing lacks any high side driver, and relies on a pullup resistor.  You really want an output that drives actively in both directions, or else you need to understand the ESC input circuit.

Comment: How hard would it be to implement a high side driver? I just find it annoying/hard to believe that intel advertises this thing as a drone/robotics maker tool, while itself and a level shifter aren't even sufficient to drive a servo, which is like the most common robotics hardware

Comment: OKOKOK I got it to work using one transistor. I don't know how, but it works. Apparently the 5v source can be connected to either the collector or emitter, and the connection to the ESC signal wire can be both as well. The level shifted pwm signal from the edison being connected to the base.

Comment: A transistor installed with collector and emitter swapped is still a transistor to an extent, though a relatively bad one as the optimization of the internal geometry is backwards.  As for the Edison, one might say its suitability for *anything* is highly controversial - Intel's attempts to push their on-hand technologies into the "maker" / "arduino" fields seem to fairly consistently miss the mark by being overly-complicated and insufficiently-documented, causing more needless problems than solving real ones .  If you want a flight controller, get something simple like an Arm Cortex M0/3/4.

Comment: I would if there was one which had I2C and pwm capabilities, and was comparable in size to the Edison. The Edison's Atom is plenty fast enough for the number of floating point calculations in my controller (which is quite a lot), it's just the pwm probably doesn't have good enough resolution to correctly implement the prop rates. But we will see soon enough.

Answer (score 4):

The Intel Edison has 1.8V I/O voltage as compared to the Arduino with 5V. 
That's almost surely your problem.

You would need a voltage translator such as [this one- a 74AXP1T125](http://cache.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74AXP1T125.pdf) to increase the voltage.

If it really is current (as your added comment on using a voltage translator would seem to indicate) then you can add a buffer to the voltage translator. For example, the 74LVC1G17SE-7 can drive +/-32mA. If you parallel inputs and outputs on a dual (eg. [NC7WZ16](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/NC/NC7WZ16.pdf)) you can drive 60mA with a 5V supply.

Comment: Natively yes, but many of the solutions the poster might be using to breakout the tiny board-to-board connector of the module appear to have translation built in, at least for some of the signals.

Comment: Ugh I knew someone would point that out. I should have said I am also using a level shifter to get the signal to 5 volts.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit to include the option-adding a buffer if it really is current, but that does not make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: I know, it seemed unlikely to me too, and it was the last thing I looked at, but experimentation with the signal generator showed that the ESC is remarkably permissive regarding signal input: I could DC offset the signal by +- 1 volt and even decrease the output to only 3v (with a DC offset!) and the ESC still accepted the signal as long as the period and duty cycle were the same. Which tells me that the error had to be with the amount of current, since voltage characteristics hardly matter apparently.

Comment: @ThomasKirven - no, it is not the current - if it were that, you would see the voltage dropping severely once the ESC was connected.  You are misinterpreting things.  Chances are your MCU is not outputting what you think in terms of signal timing, or you have not gone through the necessary sequence to unlock the arming safety of the motor controller.

Comment: I hope you are using an oscilloscope, as @Chris says, this does not smell right.

Comment: I have used an 2 channel oscilloscope and literally compared the arduino signal and edison signal side by side. the are the same: -both 5v high, 0 v low, both have a period of 400 hz, both have duty cycle of 1-2 ms. Arduino signal is accepted with no arming sequence, just the static signal, and the Edisons is not.

Comment: Then you **do not have a current problem**.  If you did, the scope would show the ESC loading the voltage down and it would no longer be the same.   What have you done about the arming sequence?  As for your claim to have compared them "side by side" - how did you get a stable trigger on two asynchronous sources?

Comment: See above comment. By the way I really appreciate everyones feedback on this. Also I do not connect the oscilloscope and the ESC at the same time. I connect the oscilloscope and make sure the signal is correct then unplug and plug into the ESC.

Comment: You have to connect the ESC while you are measuring, otherwise the measurement does not capture the operational situation.

Comment: Ok I will do that, but the chances of the pwm drivers failing only when not plugged into the oscilloscope are 1 in ten billion.

Comment: Actually the chance the signal fails when the ESC is connected is 100%... that is, unless you are wrong in your insistence that the problem has to do with current.

Comment: Battery is charging right now, but when it's finished I will connect ESC and oscilloscope. What do you mean by the signal fails when  the ESC is connected? Is it really that unreasonable that the low current should be the problem?? It's just that I have been on this problem for 3 days and have checked everything I can think of, and the current is the only difference between the Edison and Arduino Signal.

Comment: The current measurement you took is meaningless since the conditions are too drastically different from the ones that matter.  Measure the voltage with the scope *under load* and you can make educated guesses about the magnitude of current in the situation that matters, by seeing how much the load makes the voltage drop over what it is unloaded.

Comment: @ChrisStratton is 100% right- there are other possible problems that seem much more likely. A typical ESC has an input impedance of many K ohms so the output drive capability is immaterial.

Comment: Remember that your logical level shifter is another point of failure.  I would redo your measurements but now putting a load resistor before and after your Edison board to check signal integrity.  For the case after the shifter use two 100 \$\Omega\$ resistors in parallel as the load (just in case the resistors are rated 1/8 W). For the before the shifter case use 3 100 \$\Omega\$ resistors.

Answer (score 0):

You could Use a Couple of transistors to Boost the voltage, if you have a 5V source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY5ifw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @ThomasKirven I did make a slight error. Buff R1 up to something above 1K

Comment: This only drives high through a 10K pullup resistor.  If the asker is worried about drive strength that is hardly a solution.  Chances are the problem itself is misidentified, but if proposing a solution something with active drive would be better.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The asker is worried about **signal** *Voltage*, as stated in the question, (s)he wants to be able to deliver a proper pwm signal, but the Edison only provides 1.8V. 10kOhm @ 5V is enough to drive a PWM signal for an ESC.

Comment: @tuskiomi - not necessarily, no.  It will not, for example drive an optocoupler input.  And if there is noise suppression circuitry it may be insufficient.  **This is a bad proposal** that is only likely to waste their time - it's probably not addressing the real problem, and even if the problem is what you assume, this is a bad way to do it as it is overly complicated and has poor performance.

Comment: NO, I am worried about CURRENT. The signal voltage is fine. see the Edited question

Comment: @ThomasKirven, let me get this straight, are you looking for a solution that will increase your PWM signal strength, or increase what the ESC puts out?

Comment: I am asking for a solution that will increase the current delivered in the pwm signal. The signal itself (period and duty cycle) are fine, but the Edison pwm lines don't source very much current. I need to boost the current without changing the period or duty cycle of the signal.

Comment: @ThomasKirven alright, then a modified version of this circuit should work. I'll edit my answer quick

Comment: @ThomasKirven Edits finished.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have edited the schematic to a more proper solution.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I thought the states were *high* (1.8V) and *low* (GND). Thus, when the pin is LOW, the wire would be grounded, and the transistor would shut off.

Comment: @ChrisStratton What do you think is the problem? Is it that the Edison's signal is somehow failing when it is connected to the ESC?

Comment: @ThomasKirven IF i'm reading correctly, He thinks that the Edison operates on an High/float operation, where the edison has no pulling resistors, thus is a pin is turned to HIGH then OFF, the pin would stay at 1.8V until drained. This would a minor problem, but not one of much notice, as transistor allow current flow from base to ground: http://www.radartutorial.eu/21.semiconductors/pic/transistor10.print.png 
I think that the Edison has pullup resistors, so that the on/off states are HIGH and GND, meaning that a pin is grounded (+0V) if it's not high, as opposed to floating.

Comment: Yes the edison has internal pulp and pulldown resistors (2k 20k and 50k) on all its gpios including PWM. But from what I understand the PWM driver itself is dedicated to bringing the line high and low depending on the set period and duty cycle, so using the pulling resistors won't have much effect on the pwm lines

Comment: @ThomasKirven Well, I could see that his concern was valid, and added the proper component. This is really starting to get unnecessary, though.

Comment: No, no, and no.  The bare Edison you are still trying to assist rather obviously drives both high and low, but its high and low, not yours.  Your current transistor circuit has a lower output voltage than the Edison by itself.  It's probably best you just delete this as it's far removed from the question **it has already been established that in the configuration used level conversion is already provided by the carrier**. If you want to ask your own question on designing a converter form 1.8v to 5v using bipolar transistors you can, but it is *a lot harder* than you seem to think it will be.

Comment: @ChrisStratton it's not a converter. it's a switch. You use 1.8V to turn on the 5V switch. what's so hard to understand?

Comment: What do you imagine the voltage on the emitter will be?  The voltage on the base?  What will VBE then be?   Build it.  You will see that it doesn't work.  But the problems with your circuit are not relevant to the question, because the problem it is trying to solve is not the problem of the question.

Comment: What you have designed in the current iteration is not a "switch" but rather an **emitter follower**.  An emitter follower does not have voltage gain.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've drawn a shitty diagram of my hypothesized operation, with current flow in bright blue: http://imgur.com/a/calRf

Comment: In neither case is your transistor active.  Post this as your own question if you want to understand it, but delete it here where it is misleading and irrelevant.

Comment: @ThomasKirven it seems that my first circuit was correct.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Really appreciate your help. So to be clear the circuit you drew increases current? I have since connected the oscilloscope and ESC concurrently and the high voltage drops from 5v to 2v when the pwm is connected to the ESC. I'm not entirely sure why though.

Comment: And thanks @tuskiomi, I don't know who is right but there does seem to be solutions here somewhere

Comment: @ThomasKirven I have another question going, and it seems that Chris talked me out of a correct solution, the one currently in the answer.

Comment: This is not a "correct" solution.  You might find a resistor value where you "get away with it" (you've reduced the value now by a factor of 20!) but really you want an active driver.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't think you know how much current is needed to read a PWM signal....

Comment: Rather obviously, you don't either.  None of us do - because we don't know the details of what it is driving.  I've seen examples where micramps would do it, and others that needed 10-20mA or so.  What makes this "incorrect" is that it is far more sensitive to unknown details of the receiver than an actively bi-directional driver would be.